# Can the set $\{(0,1),(3,4),(-1,-2)\}$ generate $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: vectors

So a question in an assignment has me a bit stuck. Can the set of the following vectors $\{ (0,1),(3,4),(-1,-2) \}$ generate the space $\mathbb{R}^2$?

My initial approach was trying to find three scalars $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ that could be multiplied by each vector and equal to a general vector $(x,y)$ in order to create a system of equations, whose solution would be the value of each scalar. However, this approach creates a system with 2 equations with 3 variables; and I am skeptical that a free variable would be appropriate in this question.

Comment: The punchline is that yes they do, and even more than that... you could show something stronger that merely using $\{(0,1),(3,4)\}$ would have been sufficient as well and the additional vector was unnecessary.  Feel free to prove this stronger result instead.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh lol indeed it works for any value of γ and does generate R² as does the set without the third vector. Nice!
Thanks for the response.

Comment: Incidentally, they even generate $\mathbb{R}^2$ as an affine space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}, x,y\in\mathbb R
$$ be an arbitrary vector. We want to find $\alpha, \beta,\gamma$, such that
$$
\alpha\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
+\beta\cdot\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}
+\gamma\cdot\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}.
$$

First we can see, that
$$
-3\cdot \begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}
+
(-2)\cdot \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
This means, that these three vectors create the $\mathbb R^2$ if and only if the two vectors $\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ do so. So we check
$$
\alpha\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
+\beta\cdot\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}.
$$
This leads to the system
$$
\begin{vmatrix} 
0\cdot \alpha - 1\cdot\beta &= x \\
\alpha -2\beta &= y
\end{vmatrix}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{vmatrix} 
-\beta &= x \\
\alpha -2\beta &= y
\end{vmatrix}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{vmatrix} 
\beta &= -x \\
\alpha -2\beta &= y
\end{vmatrix}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{vmatrix} 
\beta &= -x \\
\alpha  &= y-2x
\end{vmatrix}.
$$

This is a unique solution, so for every vector in $\mathbb R^2$, we find coefficients. Hence, these two create the $\mathbb R^2$, so every superset (like yours) does.